# determining meaning of basic biological keywords about C. elegans

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing

First of all I have to say that I have no biology background since I'm a undergraduate computer science student. Nowadays, for my research I need to use some of the databases related with bioinformatics (`modENCODE` and `NCBI-GEO`). Currently, I'm searching RNA-Seq data and I have found the following one in modENCODE website which is stored in NCBI-GEO database.[RNA-Seq data](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/sra.cgi?cmd=viewer&m=data&s=viewer&run=SRR360120)

In the description part of it, it is written that:

> Synchronized L1 worms cultured at 25degC for about 91 hrs to a point
>   at which ~100% worms are resistant to 1% SDS treatment. Illumina
>   sequencing of C. elegans dauer daf-2(el370) sample 2-1 DauerDAF2-2-1
>   polyA+ RNAseq random fragment library This sample is available through
>   the modENCODE DCC (www.modencode.org) as: DauerDAF2-2-1 Local library
>   name: DauerDAF2-2-1 Quality values are ASCII encoded Phred + 33.

Regarding with this paragraph, I want to ask that, what is `C. elegans dauer daf-2(el370)` . I've searched on the internet and I have found that `dauer` is kind of development stage of *C. elegans*. However, I could not find any information about the `daf-2(el370)` part (Actually all I found was that daf-2 is name of a gene of *C. elegans*). Actually, my primarily concern is whether this RNA-Seq data contains the *C. elegans*' whole transcriptome or it contains only mRNAs related with daf-2 gene.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but daft-2(el370) looks an awful lot like a nomenclature of a transgenic worm. And RNA Seq doesn't do it on a gene by gene basis if I remember my basics. It does it on the whole transcriptome.

Comment: @RoverEye Although I have limited information, I agree that RNA-Seq does it on the whole transcriptome, I just wanted to be approved. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I think it is daf-2 mutant which prolongs dauer stage. Did you read the corresponding paper??

Comment: @WYSIWYG corresponding paper is not available to publicly access therefore I could not read it.

Comment: @stackunderflow Here you go: http://genome.cshlp.org/content/19/4/657.long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you discovered [wormbase](http://www.wormbase.org) yet? It will become your new best friend. In worms gene names reflect the loss-of-function (lf) phenotype. Daf means "abnormal DAuer Formation," so *daf-2* was the second daf gene identified ([ref](http://www.wormbase.org/species/c_elegans/gene/WBGene00000898#0-9f-3)). The mutations are called alleles and each worm lab has their own allele designation. *e* was for England and in that lab's strain list the *daf-2* allele was the 1,370th on their list. So *daf-2(e1370)* designation means that the strain carries a lf mutation in the *daf-2* gene, and the specific allele is one that was isolated in Cambridge, UK. I believe that allele is temperature-sensitive (*ts*) dauer-constitutive.
So at 25⁰C 100% of the animals were dauers. That is when they harvested RNA. It is the entire transcriptome. It sounds like you may be familiar with [modENCODE Data Warehouse](http://intermine.modencode.org). You can still ask questions about modENCODE datasets at [help@modencode.org](http://mailto:help@modencode.org). While the modENCODE Data Coordination Center was mothballed at the end of the NIH funding period, there are a few people who still field queries like yours, to the Helpdesk. Also, moving forward the new ENCODE DCC has taken over curation of archival modENCODE metadata.